# How to get the start and end number of an Element?

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I need to know the line number and column of start and end of an `Element` from the `Analyzer` package.

For example:

```dart
// Some class
class Foo {
  String bar = '';
}
```

The `Foo` class starts at line 2 column 0 and ends at line 4 column 0.
How can I know that from `ClassElement`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to get the `AstNode` from an `Element`:

```dart
AstNode getAstNodeFromElement(Element element) {
  final session = element.session;
  final parsedLibResult = session!.getParsedLibraryByElement(element.library!)
      as ParsedLibraryResult;
  final elDeclarationResult = parsedLibResult.getElementDeclaration(element);
  return elDeclarationResult!.node;
}
```

The `AstNode` has `offset` and `end` integers that mark the location in the dart file.